# load specific div of another site to my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

I searched for this code for load specific div from another site can any one write an example for this code in jsfiddle???

```
    $.ajax({
url: 'http://something.com',
type: 'GET',
success: function(res) {
var loadIt = $j(res.responseText).find('#divname').html();
$('#m').html(loadIt);
}
});
```

if is a better way ?????

Comment: in fact he can by using some kind of server side proxy script for that. possibly written in php :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the JQuery load method.
Give this a try : $('#m').load(url);

Comment: That won't work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy